# Scroll Bar в RecyclerView изменяется при прокрутке

Tags: java, android, adapter, recyclerview

Есть `Adapter` для `RecyclerView`:

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] items = {"My items"};


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    //items = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_text_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((TextView)holder.mTextView.findViewById(R.id.textItemTextView)).setText(items[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
}
```

Ячейки получаются разной высоты и при скролле этого списка, ползунок в правой части экрана меняет свой размер и вообще ведёт себя не адекватно, это связано с тем что ячейки разного размера. Как это пофиксить?
В iOS вызывается метод `heightForRowAtIndexPath` для каждой ячейки, и он возвращает её высоту, из этих данных оно само делает высоту скролла, а в Андроиде я такого не нашёл.